# Requesting Explanation of Picture Proof : Union Distributes over Intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Union_Distributes_over_Intersection has an explanation on how the **union distributes over the intersection**. I understand the element argument proof and want to understand the alternative picture proof. [Picture 1](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/File:UnionDistOverInt2.png)
[Picture 2](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/File:UnionDistOverInt2.png)

[image]

I am requesting a narration on the picture proof provided. I can't follow the logic or their picture is wrong.

The picture is attempting to show $R∪(S∩T)=(R∪S)∩(R∪T)$.

---

### Question 2

Here is the picture showing that **intersection distributes over union**. It is showing $R∩(S∪T)=(R∩S)∪(R∩T)$ :

from proofwiki.com

[image]

Comment: Part of the problem might be that the proof they have is showing that $R \cup (S \cap T) = (R \cup S) \cap (R \cup T)$, and what you've written is $R \cap (S \cup T) = (R \cap S) \cup (R \cap T)$.

Comment: @DuncanRamage I fixed what you said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture is actually showing that $R\cup (S\cap T) = (R\cup S) \cap (R\cup T)$. In the first picture, $R$ is blue/green, $S\cap T$ is yellow/green, and their union is nonwhite.

In the second picture, $R\cup S$ is yellow/green, $R\cup T$ is blue/green, and their intersection is green. We can see that the nonwhite region in the first picture is the same as the green region in the second, thus proving the theorem.